# How to Iterate testng.xml file for different credentials and application urls

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running my testng.xml using a batch file. I need to run the same testng.xml multiple times with different urls (Say 10 urls). The test cases remain same for all the Urls.

I am giving the Application Urls in the property file. Currently I have only 1 url in the property file and I am changing the url manually. I want to automate this

I want separate emailable testng report for each iteration

Comment: The wants are all clear. Can you please edit your question and share what you have as code so far, and where you are stuck and need help?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maven to run, you can pass mvn -Durl="ur url"